# Translate words into the class component (.ts) with ngx-translate (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I want to translate the content of a table into my typescript class. The table's data are fetched from JSON file located into /assets.

Is there a way to achieve that?
How I can mark translation into a typescript class?
PS: Please do not suggest doing it into the HTML, since it is not the desired way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the `ngx-translate` [docs](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive), you can achieve that by injecting the `TranslateService` into your class constructor, then use one of the following methods:

```js
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  // Using `instant` function:
  const translatedValueUsingInstant = this.translate.instant(
    'KEY_STORED_IN_TRANSLATION_FILE'
  );

  // OR using `get` function:
  let translatedValueUsingGet: string;
  this.translate
    .get('KEY_STORED_IN_TRANSLATION_FILE')
    .subscribe((value) => (translatedValueUsingGet = value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same problem, but here is the solution that worked for me.

```js
//Ts file

translatedString: string = 'KEY_STORED_IN_TRANSLATION_FILE'
```

```html
<!-- HTML file -->

<li> {{ translatedString | translate }} </li>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).